# How can I run wire rope around the corner of my railing with a turnbuckle?

Tags: roof, exterior, patio, wire, steel

I have a rooftop that looks like the following. I'll be using turnbuckles to connect each tube to the wire rope.

The issue is: what do I do with the corner tubes? If I use the turnbuckles for the corner, I'll have a loophole that won't be used. Also, how do I connect the corner tube to the tube next to it?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why would you use so many turnbuckles? Normally a cable runs through the entire system with a single turnbuckle at one end. Anyway, the answer probably involves replacing a turnbuckle with a threaded eyebolt.

Comment: I made the drawing to explain the issue. The threaded eyebolt would thread into the tube, which worries me a bit. At least the turnbuckles connect to each other.

Comment: You are putting the turnbuckles inside the tubes?